# WPF - Hidden Window Shows In Screenshot

Tags: wpf, screenshot

My simple goal is to take a screenshot.
My application has a main window that has multiple purposes and one of them is taking a screenshot.

What I do is hide the window by using `MainWindow.Hide();` and then showing a second window that handles the screenshot taking process.

```
 this.Hide();
 SnapshotManager snapshotMgr = new SnapshotManager();
 snapshotMgr.Closed += SnapshotMgrClosed;
 snapshotMgr.Show();
```

The second window is basically this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="MainImage" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    </Image>
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

with the properties:

```
AllowsTransparency="True"
Background="Transparent"
WindowStyle="None"
```

When the user clicks a button to take the screenshot I hide the main window and show this one.
Then I save the screen to the image in my second window like so:

```
Bitmap snapshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,       Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(snapshot);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(0,0), new System.Drawing.Point(0,0), Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

//-----------------------------------
// Save the screen to MainImage
//-----------------------------------
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
snapshot.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
ms.Position = 0;
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();

MainImage.Source = bi;
```

The problem is that for some reason my main window shows up in the screenshot.
The MainWindow.Hide() probably doesn't work like I think it does.
How can I take a screenshot with the main window?

Thank you!

Edit:
The following code works but uses Sleep(200) which I really would like to avoid.

```
private void OnTakeSnapshot(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.LayoutUpdated += RunSnapshotMgr;
    this.Hide();
}

private void RunSnapshotMgr(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsVisible == true) return;
    Thread.Sleep(200);

    SnapshotManager snapshotMgr = new SnapshotManager();
    snapshotMgr.Closed += SnapshotMgrClosed;
    snapshotMgr.Show();

    this.LayoutUpdated -= RunSnapshotMgr;
}
```

Comment: maybe your window has not been actually hidden at the time the screen is captured. You can try adding the capturing code inside some `IsVisibleChanged` handler for the main window, check if the `IsVisible` is `false` to run your code. You should register the handler first, then call `Hide()`. In the handler, after running the capturing code, you should unregister the handler.

Comment: @KingKing Didn't work :(